# Unable To Get Available Memory With sysconf()

Tags: c++, memory

Why does `sysconf()` return the same new memory byte value after a new integer array is allocated and filled with zeros?  Is there a way to get the real-time available memory with C++ and Ubuntu?

```
#include <unistd.h>

unsigned long long int mem;
mem = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES)*sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
std::cout << "available memory  " << mem << std::endl;
int* g = new int[2000000000]();
usleep(1000*1000);
mem = sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES)*sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);
std::cout << "g array size  " << 2000000000*sizeof(int) << std::endl;
std::cout << "available memory  " << mem << std::endl;
usleep(1000*1000);
```

Comment: are you confusing `_SC_PHYS_PAGES` with `_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES` ? From documention I would expect `_SC_PHYS_PAGES` to be constant

Comment: The pages allocated by `int* g = new int[2000000000]();` might not be committed until you write something other than `0` to them as most OSs can fill uncommitted pages with 0s when required to commit them.

Comment: @RichardCritten the ```()``` at the end fills the memory with zeros.  Without it, it is not committed.  I can see the memory filling in my system monitor.

Comment: @alvrm is was reasoning that - the fill with `0`s might be being ignored because newly commit pages might be filled with 0s by the OS/page mechanism and the tool-chain knows this.

Answer (score 2):

Credit to ***@463035818_is_not_a_number***

Using `_SC_AVPHYS_PAGES` instead of `_SC_PHYS_PAGES` worked.